# Laravel 500 Internal Server Error after Composer Update

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, internal-server-error

I wanted to create a new blog so I tried, then was greeted with this message:

> This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is
>   recommended to update it by running "/usr/local/bin/composer
>   self-update" to get the latest version.

So I did, and it seemed fine, then I created the blog and I got this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Then I went to the directory of the blog and executed this command

> > chmod 755 -R storage

So as to allow composer to log my errors, the command seemed to be executed properly, I refreshed my blog in the browser and still, 500 error, so I check the logs, and still nothing, it is still not logging anything.

Then I check my previous projects and they had a 500 internal server error too.

I have probably tried solutions from 20+ different forums and threads and nothing will work. I have changed my .htaccess file to every variation of every correct answer I could fined (backup the original) but it is obviously not to do with the .htaccess because my previous projects worked and now they don't.

If anyone knows why this may be happening or if there's something else I should try, please help me, thank you.

Comment: Try to `tail -f` the nginx or apache access and error logs. They usually get written whenever laravel.log isn't for some reason. Also if this was a Laravel error you'd be getting the 'Whoopos' page, not this one, right ?

Comment: I called `tail -f` and refreshed the page and nothing happened, also I'm not sure, because it did say >> More information about this error may be available in the server error log

Comment: Manually check apache error logs stored at `/var/log/httpd-error.log` ?

Comment: That doesn't exist, I have an `apache2` folder in my log folder though, I'm using a Macbook Pro Yosemite

Comment: On osx you can track errors via the 'Console' app.

Comment: http://imgur.com/d9CJhvD This is what I see in the console app when I refresh the page please tell me this will help solve the problem??

Comment: The console app error shows that apache service exited with abnormal code. So I guess there may be some problem with your apache config. I don't have a mac so will not be able to help much. Are you able to ping 127.0.0.1:80 (localhost)?

Comment: @Donkarnash I made a new thread that maybe you could help me with that  because the php wont execute ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498900/starting-stopping-or-restarting-apachectl-always-returns-ifmodule-without-m